# Regular expression that accepts digits, letters and hyphens

Tags: c#, regex, validation, webforms

I want a regular expression that accepts all numbers, alphabets and only the hyphen (‐) from special characters.

I am trying this expression: `^\d+$/[-]/[a-z]` but it does not work. I want to accept expressions like this one:

```
Emp-IN-0000001
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's always this format (Emp-IN-0000001), then use this regexp:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-[0-9]+$
```

or, if you have extended regexps:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]{2}-\d+$
```

when there are always seven digits, use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]{2}-\d{7}$
```

You can even say:

```
^Emp-IN-\d{7}$
```

if it's exactly "Emp-IN-" + digits.

Btw, this is not C# specific, you can use these regular expressions with any language, as long as they support regexps at all.

Comment: yea its always this format only the last 2 or three digits will change ,.. thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you stickily wants to follow this format **Emp-IN-0000001**, then you might need to use this regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-\d+$
```

Comment: I guess Olaf Dietsche has beaten you to it ;)

Comment: Yea you are right, i am such a loser, saw his answer when posted mine :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you tried with your regular expression, but it is actually as simple as this:

```
^[a-zA-Z\d-]+$
```

Or if you want to allow empty strings:

```
^[a-zA-Z\d-]*$
```

If you use the case-insensitive modifier with your regular expression, you can leave out either the `a-z` or `A-Z` from both variants.

I recommend you read up on some regex basics in [this great tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).